# Efficiant way to load Wold Bank Data via WDI in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I am working on a shiny dashboard project to visualize data from the World Bank. In total i need 14 different variables that I want to show in a data table. It works in R but when I try to do it in shiny I get a connection error. I think it takes too much time to download. 
Is there a way to load the data more efficient or in background or whatever? I can't find a solution to make it run and I don't want to store the data in a file on the server because then I don't have an automatic update... :/

Here's a minimal vital code snippet

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(WDI)
library(wbstats)
library(lubridate)

ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel('WDI Example'),
   mainPanel(tableOutput('table'))

   )


server <- function(input, output) {

  startDate <- as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")) -20
  endDate <- as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))

  fetch.data <- list() 

  list <- c("SP.POP.TOTL",
            "NY.ADJ.NNTY.PC.CD",
            "SH.XPD.CHEX.PC.CD",
            "SH.XPD.OOPC.CH.ZS",
            "SH.MED.BEDS.ZS",
            "SH.MED.PHYS.ZS",
            "NY.GDP.MKTP.CD",
            "NY.GDP.MKTP.KD",
            "NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG",
            "SH.XPD.CHEX.GD.ZS",
            "SP.DYN.LE00.IN",
            "SP.POP.65UP.TO",
            "SP.POP.DPND",
            "SP.POP.DPND.OL") 

  for (i in 1:length(list)){
    fetch.data[[i]] <- WDI(indicator = as.character(list[i]),
                           start = startDate, 
                           end = endDate,
                           country = "all",
                           extra = TRUE)
  }

  data <- fetch.data


  for (i in 1:length(list)){

    data[[i]] <- subset(data[[i]], region != "Aggregates")
    data[[i]] <- data[[i]] %>% select(country, iso3c, region, year, noquote(list[i]))
    data[[i]]$date <- as.Date(as.character(date), format = "%Y")
    data[[i]] <- data[[i]][complete.cases(data[[i]][ ,5]),]
    data[[i]] <- data[[i]] %>% group_by(country) %>% arrange(desc(date)) %>% slice(1)
  }


  indicators <- fetch.data[[1]] %>% 
    select(country, iso3c, region) %>% 
    subset(region != "Aggregates") %>% 
    arrange(desc(country)) %>% 
    group_by(country) %>% 
    slice(1)


  for (i in 1:length(list)){
    indicators <- merge(indicators, data[[i]][ ,c(2,5)], by.x = "iso3c", by.y = "iso3c", all = TRUE)
  }


  indicators <- indicators %>% 
    arrange(country) %>% 
    mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 2)

  output$table <- renderTable(indicators)

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and here is an example that does not work… https://thera-trainer.shinyapps.io/example/

Thanks for advice

Comment: Can you put the error message in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Error**

Your error is in this line of code:

```r
data[[i]]$date <- as.Date(as.character(date), format = "%Y")
```

`date` is a function (closure), which is why you are getting an error. If you mean to refer to a column in your dataframe, you would need to use `data[[i]]$date`, as in

```r
data[[i]]$date <- as.Date(as.character(data[[i]]$date), format = "%Y")
```

You are likely used to the tidyverse where you aren't required to prefix columns with their dataframe, but when using non-tidyverse operations, like `<-`, you must include the dataframe name as well. In addition, there is no column in `data[[i]]` called `date`, so even if you had used `as.Date(as.character(data[[i]]$date), format = "%Y")` you would have received an error because that column doesn't exist.

Further, it looks like you are trying to convert a date to a year, but there is already a column in `data[[i]]` called `year`, you can refer to it with `data[[i]]$year`.

**Code Style**

It is not good practice to name your objects with names that match those of a function. You have done this twice, once by assigning `fetch.data` to `data` (there is already a function `utils::data()`, and more importantly you have assigned your indicators to a variable called `list`. This is **extremely** dangerous, as you have overwritten the `list()` function in your global environment, and to use the list function again later on you will have to call it with `base::list()`. I would recommend a more emotive name for the indicators, such as:

```r
indicators_list <- c("SP.POP.TOTL",
            "NY.ADJ.NNTY.PC.CD",
            "SH.XPD.CHEX.PC.CD",
            "SH.XPD.OOPC.CH.ZS",
            "SH.MED.BEDS.ZS",
            "SH.MED.PHYS.ZS",
            "NY.GDP.MKTP.CD",
            "NY.GDP.MKTP.KD",
            "NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG",
            "SH.XPD.CHEX.GD.ZS",
            "SP.DYN.LE00.IN",
            "SP.POP.65UP.TO",
            "SP.POP.DPND",
            "SP.POP.DPND.OL")
```

**withProgress**

There is a [Shiny progress indicator](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html) you can use to monitor loops that take a long time. You would include it like this;

```r
  withProgress(
    for (i in 1:length(indicators_list)){
      incProgress(1/length(indicators_list), detail = paste("Doing part", i))
      fetch.data[[i]] <- WDI(indicator = indicators_list[i],
                             start = startDate, 
                             end = endDate,
                             country = "all",
                             extra = TRUE)
  })
```

**Complete Example**

Here is a complete example that I was able to get working. I have only included the server component as that is the only one where I made changes.

```r
server <- function(input, output) {

  startDate <- as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")) -20
  endDate <- as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))

  fetch.data <- list() 

  indicators_list <- c("SP.POP.TOTL",
                  "NY.ADJ.NNTY.PC.CD",
                  "SH.XPD.CHEX.PC.CD",
                  "SH.XPD.OOPC.CH.ZS",
                  "SH.MED.BEDS.ZS",
                  "SH.MED.PHYS.ZS",
                  "NY.GDP.MKTP.CD",
                  "NY.GDP.MKTP.KD",
                  "NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG",
                  "SH.XPD.CHEX.GD.ZS",
                  "SP.DYN.LE00.IN",
                  "SP.POP.65UP.TO",
                  "SP.POP.DPND",
                  "SP.POP.DPND.OL") 

  withProgress(
    for (i in 1:length(indicators_list)){
      incProgress(1/length(indicators_list), detail = paste("Doing part", i))
      fetch.data[[i]] <- WDI(indicator = indicators_list[i],
                             start = startDate, 
                             end = endDate,
                             country = "all",
                             extra = TRUE)
  })

  data <- fetch.data


  for (i in 1:length(indicators_list)){

    data[[i]] <- subset(data[[i]], region != "Aggregates")
    data[[i]] <- data[[i]] %>% select(country, iso3c, region, year, noquote(indicators_list[i]))
    data[[i]]$date <- data[[i]]$year
    data[[i]] <- data[[i]][complete.cases(data[[i]][ ,5]),]
    data[[i]] <- data[[i]] %>% group_by(country) %>% arrange(desc(date)) %>% slice(1)
  }


  indicators <- fetch.data[[1]] %>% 
    select(country, iso3c, region) %>% 
    subset(region != "Aggregates") %>% 
    arrange(desc(country)) %>% 
    group_by(country) %>% 
    slice(1)


  for (i in 1:length(indicators_list)){
    indicators <- merge(indicators, data[[i]][ ,c(2,5)], by.x = "iso3c", by.y = "iso3c", all = TRUE)
  }


  indicators <- indicators %>% 
    arrange(country) %>% 
    mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 2)

  output$table <- renderTable(indicators)

}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you found the answer useful, consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it so that others with the same question may find the answer.